# Should I accept if the answer says "it can't be done"?

Tags: discussion, accepting

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85128/8141) replies to the question by saying *this is not possible*. Normally, I should accept an answer if it solves my problem. Although the answer *It's not possible* is probably correct, should I accept it or not if it doesn't solve my problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An "accepted answer" is one that is the most helpful to you.  Being helpful, can include the useful information that you should not waste your time on this because what you are trying is impossible.  Thus it may well be appropriate to accept such an answer.

Comment: though it could be appropriate to wait a bit before accepting because what one thinks impossible might turn out not be after all. Sometimes someone else comes along and provides a solution.

Answer (score 16):

One thing I didn't realise when I started here is that one can unaccept an answer and then accept a new one. So I would suggest accepting the "impossible" answer, assuming it is credible (for the reasons Andrew Swann gives); if a solution does turn up later, you can always accept that instead.